# Set tweets counts for each items in tweepy stream

Tags: python, twitter, filter, stream, tweepy

I have a problem and cant get to a solution..
I have written a python script to Stream twitter tweets.
My issue is I need to read 5 tweets for each words in the given list.

## Below is the code:

```
class TweetListener(StreamListener):

    def on_status(self,status):           
        print "TWEET ARRIVED!!!"
        print "Tweet Text : %s" % status.text
        print "Author's name : %s" % status.author.screen_name
        print "Time of creation : %s" % status.created_at
        print "Source of Tweet : %s" % status.source    
        time.sleep(10)       
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):        
        print status
        if status == 420:
            print "Too soon reconnected, Exiting!!"
            return False
        sys.exit()


def search_tweets():
    twitterStream = Stream(connect().auth, TweetListener())        
    twitterStream.filter(track=['Cricket','Maths','Army','Sports'],languages = ["en"],async=True)
```

## Here I need to get 5 tweets each for Cricket, Maths, Army & Sports

What I am getting is an infinite number of tweets for the above elements.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks & regards.

Comment: What in your code is supposed to limit the number of returned tweets?

Comment: Aah somewhat yes. I need a limited number of tweets for each item, say 4 or 5 tweets only for each

Comment: the whole idea of streaming is to get an infinite number of tweets. you need to either turn the stream off once you harvest tweets to your hearts desire, or use the RESTful api and retrieve your desired number of (past) tweets that way

Comment: Okay, can I get the element name for which the tweet has arrived? Like 

Tweet arrived for 'Cricket'
...rest of the print statement goes here....

Tweet arrived for 'Sports'
...rest of the print statement goes here....

Comment: Why are you using a `StreamListener` for this? Do you need to return tweets as they happen or are you interested in tweets that already exist?

Comment: If the current streaming doesn't work with a fixed no of tweets, then i find no help but to pick already existing ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class TweetListener(StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, list_=None,dict_= None):
        self.keys_= list_
        self.dict = dict_

    def on_status(self, status):   
        str_ = status.text.lower()        
        for key in self.dict.keys():
            if key.lower() in str_.lower():
                if self.dict[key] <= 0:
                    return True
                else:
                    self.dict[key] -=1
                    self.performAction(key,status)                                     

        if all(value == 0 for value in self.dict.values()):
            return False

    def on_error(self, status):        
        print status
        if status == 420:
            print "Too soon reconnected . Will terminate the program"
            return False
        sys.exit()      


def create_dict(list_):
    no_of_tweets = 5
    dict_ =  {k:no_of_tweets for k in list_ }
    return dict_


def search_tweets():
    search_word = ['Cricket','Maths','Army','Sports']    
    twitterStream = Stream(connect().auth, TweetListener(list_=search_word , dict_=create_dict(search_word)))
    twitterStream.filter(track=search_word ,languages = ["en"],async=True)
```

Here I initialize a list with all the required words that are to be searched for tweets, then I create a dictionary with key:value as word_to_be_searched:count_as_5 in the ***create_dict(list_)*** function, like Cricket:5, Maths:5, Army:5, Sports:5 and so on. Then I pass the list along with the dictionary to the TweetListener class.

I override the on_status function to retrieve tweets and then compare the tweets with the key field of my dictionary. It is obvious there will be a match and then, in that case, I decrease the value(as counter here) by 1. 
When all the values become 0, then I return false to break the loop and close the thread.

[**Note**, if any value corresponding to a key has become zero, it indicates that the required no of tweets are already captured so we will not proceed with any more tweets on that word.]

Then in the ***performAction(key, status)*** function {key=one of the searched words and status = tweet captured} I perform my required task.